# Cosine Transform of Hyperbolic Functions

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, hyperbolic-functions

Does anyone know a closed form of the integral:

$\int^{\infty}_{0}\text{d}x \cos(k x) \frac{\sinh(\frac{3\gamma-\pi}{4} x)}{\sinh(\frac{\gamma}{4} x)\cosh(\frac{2\gamma-\pi}{4} x)},$

where $\frac{\pi}{2}>\gamma>\frac{\pi}{4}$ k>0?

Best regards,
CVJM

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: This integral doesn't always converge. Do you have any restrictions on $a,b,c$?

Comment: Have specified the constants, maybe that helps?